How does SQL compare data entries?
Attempting to learn SQL, coming from a Python background.
How does SQL compare entries?
I'm used to having a variable store something, compare it to a new one, keep the old variable or store the new information as the old variable, continuing over a loop. I've noticed with SQL, looping isn't something you do a lot.
For example, here's my query from a problem on LeetCode.
recordData is a date
All other column names are int
SELECT
    w1.id as id

FROM
    Weather as w1,
    Weather as w2

WHERE
    DATEDIFF(w1.recordDate, w2.recordDate) = 1
    AND w1.temperature > w2.temperature

Would WHERE take the first w1.recordDate and compare to each w2.recordDate starting with the first then work down each w1.recordDate in this fashion?

"looping isn't something you do a lot" - You don't do it at all, because SQL is a declarative language. You use it to say what you want, not how to do it. It's important to note that FROM table1, table2 is a very old syntax that got a better alternative like 30 years ago. You're better of with FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2. That's a Cartesian product of both tables.

The implicit, comma separated join where the join conditions are in the WHERE clause corresponds to regular w1 JOIN w2 ON DATEDIFF...

The sql query in the question is an old-style join between two tables.
As Álvaro González coorectly wrote in their comment, SQL is a "declarative language, you use it to say what you want, not how to do it."
Under the hood, the database engines executing the sql statements heavily use loops.
Joins like the one in your questiin are most likely executed via nested loops:

In a nested-loop join, the database server scans the first, or outer table, and then joins each of the rows that pass table filters to the rows found in the second, or inner table.

As Álvaro González also correctly noted, you should not use thus comma-separated join syntax. Use the explicit table_a inner/left/right/full/cross join table_b on ... syntax and leave the where clause for filtering the resultset.

Would WHERE take the first w1.recordDate and compare to each w2.recordDate starting with the first then work down each w1.recordDate in this fashion?
Yes. What you do is called a cross-join (you compare every record from w1 with every record from w2).
This can explode to a huge load on the server (100 rows in w1 and 100 rows in w2 makes 10,000 row compares... imagine, when you compare two tables where each has several millions of rows...)
other join types are inner join, outer join (and more) where you match two tables with a corresponding id-value of any kind in both tables.
SQL is not a programming language by definition. it has only sequences, but no loops and no conditions. when referring to loops you mean programming sql like in T-SQL (sql server) or PL/SQL (oracle). But SQL itself does not have those elements.
It is split into the DDL Data Definition Language containing CREATE,ALTER,DROP, the DML Data Manipulation Language containing the crud operations INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE and SELECT and the DCL Data Control Language caring about permissions with GRANT and REVOKE.
It is a query language and best to compare with the set theory.
